# Как вернуть сразу несколько переменных с виртуальной функции?

Tags: c++, функции

```
Function()
{

    x = 0;
    y = 0;

}

virtual  double Calculation (int) = 0;// базовый


virtual  double Calculation(int t)  производный
{

    y = exp(t);
    x = 2 * exp(t);

    return ;

}
```

нужно вернуть сразу и x и y.

Comment: упакуйте их в какую-нибудь структуру данных, например [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)

Answer (score 2):

Общие варианты возврата нескольких значений - через структуру или по ссылке.

Например, в вашем варианте можно воспользоваться стандартной структурой `pair`:

```
pair<double,double> Calculation(double t)
{
    pair<double,double> result;
    result.first   = exp(t);
    result.second  = 2 * exp(t);

    return result;
}
```

Или по ссылке:

```
void Calculation(double t, double& x, double& y)
{
    y = exp(t);
    x = 2 * exp(t);
}
```

ну, а в коде - что-то типа

```
double x, y;
obj.Calculation(3,x,y);
```